# Check for 401 then redirect Angularjs but only on certain routes

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui

I've got a nice angular service that checks to see if a user is logged in by looking to see if the server returns a 401 error message.  If it does, the user is redirected to a login page.

This works well, but the issue is that its completely global for all of my pages.  I have a special route that resides at **/explore** (using UI-router btw) that I want to ignore any 401s and show the page anyway without redirecting to the login page.  How would I go about making this exception for **/explore**?  My code is currently as follows:

```
  .factory('authHttpResponseInterceptor',['$q','$location',function($q,$location) {

      return {
          response: function(response){
              if (response.status === 401) {
              }

              return response || $q.when(response);
          },
          responseError: function(rejection) {
              if (rejection.status === 401) {
                  $location.path('/welcome');
              }
              return $q.reject(rejection);
          }
      };
  }])
```

Comment: You cannot change this on angular side, you have to change your server side code to allow requests from your `/explore` route. BTW, is it 404 or 401?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 401.  Late night! So there is no way to just say something like "if you're on /explore route then ignore any 401"?  I suppose I'll have to create a more fine grained login structure.

Comment: if the client side could decide this, then it's easy for unauthorized users to access your resources without login.

Comment: doodirock see my answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: Create a variable on route variable like needsAuth and then during route change event, route to login only if needsAuth is false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, pass in the specific paths you want the user to be redirected on:

```
var reservedPaths = ['/explore','/teachers','/reports'];

if (rejection.status === 401 && _.contains(reservedPaths,$location.path().trim()) {
        $location.path('/welcome');
}
```

Or you could use `$state.includes()` if you want to work with `ui-router's` states. Provide a small plunk to demonstrate the issue if the above doesn't work.

Regarding @Kanh TO's comment about the client being able to view unauthorized pages, what we do is we handle the restricted routes client side, but our web API endpoints check requests for authentication/authorization, so even if the user does fiddle with this and manage to arrive at unauthorized routes, they'll simply see a view with no data, which in my opinion is no big deal since the data is what you want unauthorized users to not see, not your app's views.

Comment: Much the same way, you can still use $location.path to watch path/state changes with UI-router, and you have some of ui-routers inbuilt utilities, `$state.is()`, `$state.includes()`...[see the docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference)